# Having trouble understanding what ker f is

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, functions

I am trying to understand what exactly 'ker f' is. My guess is that it is a set of all of the elements that were lost in the process of a mapping.

For example:
$f:A\to B$

$f = \left\{ \begin{align} \frac x2, \text{ if } x = 0 \pmod 2
\\0, \text{ if } x = 1 \pmod 2 \end{align} \right.$

Here the kernel of $f$ would contain all the values that were odd before the mapping. Is this correct?

Comment: it does not contain... it is actually equal...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik If we were only looking at a set of numbers $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$, would I have $ker \; f = \{1,3,5,7\}$ from the above function then?

Or is this notation incorrect?

Comment: for some map $f:X\to Y$, $ \mathrm{ker}(f):=\{x\in X:f(x)=0\}$. Hence if you are describing a kernel of a map you are looking for all elemnts such that the image is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I start, I should say that the function you've given, if it is from $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$, is *not* a homomorphism:
$$f(3)+f(5)=0+0=0 ~~\neq~~ 4 = f(3+5).$$

I am not used to seeing $\ker(f)$ being used for functions other than homomorphisms, but it is possible (if a little silly) to extend the usual definition for arbitrary functions $f:X\to G$, where $G$ is a group.

The usual definition for the kernel of a group homomorphism $f:G\to H$ is that $\ker(f)$ consists of all those elements in the domain which are mapped to the identity of the codomain. That is, $\{x\in G:f(x)=e_H\}$. You can of course imagine this being meaningful even when the domain is not a group, but it does not make sense when the codomain is not a group.

However, in such a case we are generally not concerned with kernels, because it turns out that what we really want a kernel to do is be a special kind of subgroup of the domain. But of course if the domain is not a group, then this notion doesn't even make sense.

[ Here is a useful exercise: prove that the above application is meaningful. In other words, show that when the domain is a group, then $\ker(f)$ really is a subgroup of its domain. And a brief followup: what does it mean if $\ker(f)$ turns out to be the trivial group? ]

[ Actually, there is an extended definition of "kernel" that would cover generic functions $X\to Y$, but I don't want to introduce any confusion. ]

Comment: This all makes perfect sense, and I have attempted both of the exercises you listed. The first I am having trouble with, but I think I can work it out. The second I believe I have proved:

$f:A \to B$
If $ker f$ is trivial, $ker f = \{1_A\}$ then we have that $f$ is injective.

If $f(x) = f(y)$ then $A_B = f(x)f(y)^{-1} = f(xy^{-1})$ hence we have $xy^{-1} = 1_A \in ker f$ Because $xy^-1 = 1_A$, $x=y$ an thus $f$ is injective.

Thank you for your help once again Eric!

Comment: If you know enough group theory, you could show that $\ker(f)$ is a _normal_ subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. The definition is that $\text{ker} f = \{x \in A | f(x) = 0\}$.

Since $0 \equiv 0\pmod{2}$, we have $f(0) = \dfrac{0}{2} = 0$, so $0 \in \text{ker} f$.

The kernel of $f$ consists of all odd integers and $0$.